# New Car - Tips for living on a muddy/bumpy road

Tags: maintenance, cleaning, rust, infiniti

I just got a used 2007 Infititi G35 with 87K miles on it. I'm determined to take great care of it. I live on a muddy, bumppy road that leads to my house major pot holes. I rent the home and I'm trying to get the landlord to lay down some gravel. Until that happens what's the best way to take care of it, tips for cleaning, any other major concerns I should be aware of?

Answer (score 3):

I own a Genesis, a Miata and a Tiburon. They all seem to hold up well. We live in a VERY rural area with dirt roads and it rains a lot. What I've found is that you should wash the cars every 2 - 3 days. This keeps the pollen, dirt and mold off of it so you don't prematurely destroy the paintjob. I also have gotten into the habit of hosing down my brakes after I part it at home so that dirt and sediment doesn't stick to the rotors. Don't do that if they are hot, it will warp the rotors. I usually wait an hour and just casually hose them down. I would assume that could cause my pads to wear quicker with rock and debris on them.

Drive VERY slowly. I never get passed 5MPH on my dirt road. Some people like to speed through it, but you're going to rattle the car apart eventually. Dirt roads and potholes can cut the life of suspension components in half. I've heard some people say they spray the undercarriage, but I don't do that. When I work on my (If you do too), I always try to wipe down everything that I can to keep it clean.

These are just the things I do, but I hope it was helpful!

Comment: Will dirt really affect the paintjob anyways? It's just dirt. Pollen doesn't sound that bad either, and mold? Dirty roads make mold grow on your car?

Comment: Spraying the undercarriage doesn't have to be a big production. At my house, it's what happens while hosing down the wheels and such: walk around the car with the hose pointed up under the body. Any clean water up under there will bring out all kinds of yuck.

Comment: Dirt is comprised of many granular objects including rock and sand. They will with friction and wind speed, damage the outer coat of the vehicle. Pollen helps trap the dirt and sand on the surface of the car. I've also read that pollen can cause an excess of heat to build up which can damage the paint. Mold is just annoyance. However though, it can spread into the interior of the vehicle quite easily. It's a good idea to keep it off of the vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on the purchase! I have an '06 6mt sedan :D

In addition to frequent rinsing, make sure you still have some kind of plastic/metal shielding under the radiator/engine. My Gs prev owner had oil changes done at a quicky-lube type of place that tore off the OEM plastic undertray and never put it back on. The lack of shielding left my engine bay vulnerable to moisture and road debris, which increased accessory belt wear, mucked up my air filter, coated everything under the hood in a nasty layer of grime, decreased cooling abilities, and increased aerodynamic drag. Debris on the accessory belt also caused embarrassing squeaks and squeals that went away after I installed a replacement panel.

Multiple vendors sell Al replacements, I recommend the G35driver forums for parts and advice! If you want a little DIY project, and you happen to work or have friends that work in a metal shop you can usually get scrap Al sheeting for pretty cheap. I used .092 (13 gauge) 5052 sheet Al for mine, and crafted it using basic power tools.

Comment: Good idea on the splash guard